# SQLite: More efficient query for searching multiple terms in multiple fields

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm working with a SQLite 3 database that has to deal with a reasonably generic keyword search that searches for given terms within several (exact number currently unknown, but likely 2-5) fields.

To give an example, suppose we have a table with the columns `Title` and `Content`, and someone passes the search string `'foo bar baz'` which is then easily split into the three search terms  `foo`, `bar`, and `baz` before commencing the serach.

This all seems straightforward enough, until it comes time to generate the query. It is relatively simple with a few for loops to produce a statement like:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE (Title LIKE '%foo%' OR Content LIKE '%foo%') AND
      (Title LIKE '%bar%' OR Content LIKE '%bar%') AND
      (Title LIKE '%baz%' OR Content LIKE '%baz%')
```

and in general this should work, but it seems like a very repetitive way of structuring the query and one that could easily balloon in size if there are enough search terms and columns to check.

So my question is, is there are simpler way of structuring a statement like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you can slightly simplify the query using string concatenation:

```
WHERE (Title || ' ' || Content) LIKE '%foo%' AND
      (Title || ' ' || Content) LIKE '%bar%' AND
      (Title || ' ' || Content) LIKE '%baz%'
```

Performance is likely to be slightly worse, because of the longer strings and extra string operation.  But, the expression is simpler, and performance will be lousy anyway.

Why?  Because you are trying to replicate full text search with SQL primitives.  SQLite has full text search extensions (see [here](https://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html)); these are probably a better way to accomplish what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and I'm sorry you got downvoted - your answer is actually the kind of thing I'm looking for.

Comment: @DTR: This will work much slower that your own version. If you have a few records in the database and a few users, you will not notice a difference. Otherwise use full text search. The query will be MUCH easier, like: ... WHERE my_fts_column MATCH 'foo bar baz'

Answer (score 1):

To avoid writing a long query, you can also pass the search parameters into a [temporary table](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html) and use it in the other:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE search_terms(keyword text);
INSERT INTO search_terms VALUES ('foo');
INSERT INTO search_terms VALUES ('bar');
INSERT INTO search_terms VALUES ('baz');

SELECT DISTINCT T.title,T.content FROM table T INNER JOIN search_terms ST ON
T.title LIKE '%' || ST.keyword || '%' 
OR T.content LIKE '%' || ST.keyword || '%';
```